# How do I make a paragraph of text display as a square/rectangle in CSS

Tags: css

I have created a modal popup and have been trying to figure out how to make the text in the modal justified on top, bottom, left, and right (displaying as a rectangle/square).  I have tried `block` but is not working.

So the modal `section`  text looks something like this:

```
xxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxx
xxx xxxxx xx xxxxx xxxx xxxx  xxxx xxxxxxxx 
xxxx xxxxxxxx xx xxxxx xx xx xxxx xxx x xxxxxxx
xx x x  x xx xxxxx x x  x x xx  x xxx x x x
```

and is jagged right.

how do I make it so there is no jagged edges like.

```
xxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx xxx xxx xxxx  xx
xxx xxxxx xx xxxxx xxxx xxxx  xxxx xx   xxxxx x 
xxxx xxxxxxxx xx xxxxx xx xx xxxx xxx x xxxxxxx
xx x x  x xx xxxx x x  x   x  x xx  x xxx x x x
```

I have been trying for a while now and can't seem to get it.

EDIT:  Added CSS

```
#modal{
background-color:    #4D94B8;
outline-color:    #180238;
border: 1px solid #3B7593;
border-radius: 80px;
font-family:  arial;
text-align: justify;
display:  inline-block;
text-align:  justify;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
width:24%;
height:50%;
z-index: 1000;
margin-left: 35%;
margin-top:  7%;
}

.mHeader{
    text-decoration:    underline;
    text-align:         center;
    padding-top:      20%;
    font-size:          1vw;
}

.mButton{
    background-color:   #929292;
    border-radius: 100%;
    color:    #FFFFFF;
    text-align:center;
        height: 1.5vw;
        width: 7vw;
    margin-top:  5%;
    margin-bottom:  5%;
    margin-left:  36.5%;
    margin-right: auto;
    font-size:  .72vw;
    border-style:  none;
    border: 1px solid #666666;
}

section{
    padding-left: 10%;
    padding-top:  1%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
     font-size:  .9vw;
    font-weight:  bold;
    display:   block;
    line-height:  20px;
    margin-top:   0%;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
text-align:  justify;
}
```

Im new to web development and Im sure there is a lot of css that doesn't belong here...please don't laught at me.

EDIT:  Here is jsFiddle link:  https://jsfiddle.net/n8LLdvme/

Comment: Could you make a JSFiddle including the HTML you're using that reproduces the issue?

Comment: Give me a moment...I haven't done this before.  Only used sqlFiddle

Comment: @bjb568  I made jsFiddle (awesome I might add).  How do I post the fiddle?

Comment: just copy/paste the link here :)

Comment: (you need to press the save button in the top left first)

Comment: @bjb568 Sorry for the delay yesterday...something came up that was urgent that I needed to attend to.  Here is jsFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/n8LLdvme/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use text-align:justify and a pseudo element to avoid any text to stand on a *virtual* last line.

```css
p {
  width:18em;
  text-align:justify;
  }
p:after {/* this adds an extra invisible line, so any other line is justified */
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  width:100%;
  vertical-align:top;
  }
```

```html
<p>xxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxx
xxx xxxxx xx xxxxx xxxx xxxx  xxxx xxxxxxxx 
xxxx xxxxxxxx xx xxxxx xx xx xxxx xxx x xxxxxxx
xx x x  x xx xxxxx x x  x x xx  x xxx x x </p>
```

---

**edit Nowdays**, text-align-last is widely implemented to avoid tricks

```css
p {
  width:18em;
  text-align:justify;
  text-align-last:justify;
  }
```

```html
<p>xxxxxxxx xxx xxxx xx xxx xxxxx xxx xxxxxxxxx
xxx xxxxx xx xxxxx xxxx xxxx  xxxx xxxxxxxx 
xxxx xxxxxxxx xx xxxxx xx xx xxxx xxx x xxxxxxx
xx x x  x xx xxxxx x x  x x xx  x xxx x x </p>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I am confident that all these answers will work...however none are working for me.  I am very new to web dev and I am pretty sure there is something in my current css that is preventing the solution.  May you take a look at my css to see if anything is preventing the solution I seek?..I have already used the W3 css validator and there are no errors

Comment: @JeffOrris could you provide the html that goes along with your css. and maybe produce a snippet as i did

Answer (score 3):

What you are looking for is called text justification:

```
text-align: justify;
```

[Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/text-align) is the Mozilla Developer Network reference for text-align.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  I believe I tried that earlier and is still not working.  Let me post my CSS to the question.  I am new to web development and I am sure that there is a lot of css in there that doesn't belong....however my modal looks how I want (except for the justified text)...please don't make fun of me lol

Comment: I know this is the right answer however this is not working.  may you look at my css and advise why?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming your section is inside an element with the class `modal`:

```
.modal section{
  text-align: justify
}
```

Comment: I know this is the right answer however this is not working.  may you look at my css and advise why?

Answer (score 1):

The reason the other answers are not working is because you have line break tags inside of the paragraph. If you use the solution posted by GCyrillus and also make each section of text a paragraph, that should fix it.